# Can I share a map fragment through sockets?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app which is connecting two devices through sockets. The first one is acting as server and it is using Google Maps API v2 to find the route between my location and another location. I want to send the data to the second device which has no GPS nor internet connection. My question is can I share the map fragment from the server application with all its overlays?

Comment: *"I want to send the data to the second device which has no GPS nor internet connection".* then how are you supposed to share the data?

Comment: Good point. It's going to connect through the 3g/WiFi connection of the first device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot serialize a fragment.

One option would be to create an intent and serialize that. Something like this:

```
String uri = "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
```

There are many variations on what you can encode in the geo: scheme, so that may work for you.

Comment: Can I send only the GoogleMap object?

Comment: No it is not serializable